# Javascript function to convert list of arrays into a tree data structure or a graph

Tags: javascript, arrays, data-structures, jstree

I have a list of arrays of strings :

```
    [FT, LW ,VN ]
    [FT ,LW ,NV ]
    [FT ,LL ,VN ]
    [FT ,LL ,NV ]
    [EM ,FT ,LW ]
    [EM ,FT ,LL ]
```

Can someone please help me with a javascript function which processes these arrays and create a tree or graph like structure. 
    The final output that should look like is :

```
                FT
         LW             LL
     NV,VN,EM         VN,NV,EM
```

I am trying these functions but there seems to be an issue. I get 2 paths to start the tree. FT and EM.

```
function convertToHierarchy(arry/* array of array of strings */) {
        var item, path;
        // Discard duplicates and set up parent/child relationships
        var children = {};
        var hasParent = {};
        for (var i = 0; i < arry.length; i++) {
            var path = arry[i];
            var parent = null;
            for (var j = 0; j < path.length; j++) {
                var item = path[j];
                if (!children[item]) {
                    children[item] = {};
                }
                if (parent) {
                    children[parent][item] = true; /* dummy value */
                    hasParent[item] = true;
                }
                parent = item;
            }
        }

        // Now build the hierarchy
        var result = [];
        for (item in children) {
            if (!hasParent[item]) {
                result.push(buildNodeRecursive(item, children));
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    function buildNodeRecursive(item, children) {
        var node = {
            id : item,
            children : []
        };
        for ( var child in children[item]) {
            node.children.push(buildNodeRecursive(child, children));
        }
        return node;
    }
```

Will appreciate any help on this.

Comment: I understand that.Thanks. I have tried to build the tree structure using recursion, but that doesnt seem to work very well.

Comment: FT + LW + EM is a valid path.

Answer (score 0):

I guess I can manipulate the list to sort them based on the weight of count. And then use the initial function that I mentioned. Thanks for your help folks.